# iOS Local Notification not using Default App Logo in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

please What could be the reason for my Local notification icon on iOS to still display the default Flutter icon, even after updating my app logo, i have done flutter clean, deleted the pod files, and did pod install, uninstalled the app on my phone.

[image]

My default image is
[image]

Comment: You need to update ic_launcher icon from your mipmaps at android side.    Goto -> android/app/src/main/res here you'll see some mipmap folders for different sizes.. You can use https://www.appicon.co/ to generate your icons it'll give you mipmap folders. just replace your current mipmap folders with them.

Comment: Will this work for iOS ? @Aks

Comment: Try this : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons this can generate icons for both ios and android. For tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMHbgIgJyUQ

Comment: iOS can cache these icons, for example in the app switcher it is common to see the previous icon instead of the current. After deleting the app from the phone, try to switch off / restart the phone, reinstall the app, maybe it helps.